# How to redirect website in restricted network through ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, http, forwarding

I have established a reverse ssh tunnel into a restricted network to an `aws` server, i.e. to access it, I ssh into the `aws` server and from there I get access to the machine in the restricted network on some custom port.

On this restricted network, there are devices which can be configured through a web browser.

I believe I could do something like `ssh -R 8080:deviceIP:80 user@aws` to get it forwarded to `aws` machine but then I still can't access it (other than through remote X which is terribly slow). How can I pipe `deviceIP:80` through to my browser at home via `aws`?

I've tried the above ssh command and then directed the brower on my home computer to `aws:8080` but that didn't load any page...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SSH tunnels are useful to cross insecure networks, providing end-to-end encryption when connecting two end points that seat on distinct networks.

A far as I can tell (thanks to comments), what you have is:

- A local host-A: your `localhost`, on your local network (likely behind firewall/NAT)
- A publicly reachable host-B: the `aws` server
- A non-publicly reachable host-C: on the restricted remote network (likely behind firewall/NAT)
- A non-publicly reachable host-D: the one you refer to as `deviceIP`, that listens on port `80` and is on the remote restricted network

If you want to connect your host A to host D, letting your browser reach it on port `80`, you need:

1. A tunnel from host-A to host-B, that:

   - Lets host-A listen on port `8080`
   - Sends traffic from that port through the tunnel
   - On host-B (`aws`), redirects the traffic coming from the tunnel to the local (i.e. on host-B) port `15872` (I took it from your comments; you can choose any available port; just make sure to use the same one in all commands)

   ```bsh
   # Execute on host-A
   $ ssh -L 8080:localhost:15872 user@host-B
   ```
2. A tunnel from host-C to host-B, that:

   - Lets host-B listen on port `15872`
   - Sends traffic from that port through the tunnel
   - On host-C (your Linux server), redirects that traffic to port `80` on host-D

   ```bsh
   # Execute on host-C
   $ ssh -R *:15872:host-D:80 user@host-B
   ```

This way, requests made to host-A on port `8080` will be tunneled to host-B, redirected to port `15872` on the same host-B, tunneled to host-C and redirected on host-C to port `80` of host-D.

Comment: Ok, seems like I need something like `$ ssh -L *:8080:deviceIP:80 user@localhost  # run on aws`only that I don't have 'deviceIP' but instead a reverse tunnel on port '15872' to get access to the host in the restricted network.... so how do I need to modify this accordingly? Plus what do you mean by **It's probably not the best way** ? Is there a better way you know of?

Comment: @cerr About "It's probably not the best way", see my edited answer.

Comment: @cerr Your network topology is not entirely clear to me. Are you actually trying to connect your host (A) to a non-directly reachable remote host (C) by establishing 2 different tunnels to a publicly available host (B)? As in "A -ssh> B <ssh- C"?  If so, I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question - and I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes pretty much, what I have is (A being my private computer, B the public reachable `aws` instance, C the Linux host in the restricted network, D the device I would like to reach in the restricted network). What I have going fine is A-ssh>B-reverse ssh>C. What I would like to add: A-http8080>B-reverse ssh>C-http80>D.

Comment: @cerr Are you establishing a connection from C to B (i.e. executing a `ssh` command on the Linux host C) or the other way round?

Comment: I use autossh on C (exec command on C) to establish a reverse ssh tunnel connection on a particular PORT to B, I then connect from B by `ssh user@localhost -p PORT`

Comment: @cerr See edited answer.

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me. I do a tcpdump on `host-B` and see the `8080` requests coming in from `host-A` but doing a `tcpdump` on `host-C` for port `15872` I don't see anything coming in...

Comment: Which `tcpdump` commands did you try? I don't think host-C would see any port `15872`. Given my command (2), I think it would see packets from `host-B:22` (since I didn't explicitly set a port for connecting to `host-B`) going to its dynamically allocated port connected to `host-B`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't redirect a webserver to your browser - you would redirect requests from your browser to the webserver. It's a forward proxy, not a reverse one that you need.

This will create a listening socket on your client port 8080, and route that forwards across the `ssh` tunnel to `deviceIP` port 80:

```
ssh -L 8080:deviceIP:80 user@aws
```

Comment: But this won't forward requests sent to `aws:8080` to `deviceIP:80` - which is utltimately what I need.

Comment: That's not what you asked

Comment: Sorry, this is what I meant to ask: "How can I pipe port 80 through to my browser at home?" should have been "How can I pipe `deviceIP:80` through to my browser at home via `aws`" - I clarified the original post now

Comment: You don't pipe anything to your browser. You create a pipe, that your browser can reach, that forwards to the webserver.

Comment: @cerr What creating a tunnel with `ssh -R 8080:deviceIP:80 user@aws` does: 1) `aws` listens on port `8080` (by default, loopback interface only); 2) traffic from a connection made to `aws:8080` is tunneled to *your local host*; 3) your local host forwards it to `deviceIP:80`.

Comment: @fra-san ok, that should;ve worjked then but it didn't....when I entred `awsIP:8080` in a browser's address bar, I did not get throught to `deviceIP:80`. I opened aws inbound 8080, too (aws firewall).

Comment: @cerr I posted my own answer to clarify.